# Efficiently apply function for moving window in Python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, gdal

I'm trying to apply a local min/max stretch (or other) for a moving window over an image. It works, basically, but takes forever, since I loop over each pixel, calculate the min/max around it, stretch them to the available value range, write them and then move on. I heard about "sliced arrays" and "striding", but don't know how to adopt them. This is what I do at the moment:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal

def localStretch(image, radius, output):
    ds = gdal.Open(image, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
    drv = ds.GetDriver()
    cols = ds.RasterXSize
    rows = ds.RasterYSize
    bands = ds.RasterCount
    if os.path.exists(output):
        os.remove(output)
    out_ds = drv.Create(output, cols, rows, bands, ds.GetRasterBand(1).DataType)
    window = radius * 2 + 1
    for b in range(bands):
        data = ds.GetRasterBand(b + 1).ReadAsArray()
        out_data = np.zeros(data.shape)
        for x in range(radius, cols - radius):
            for y in range(radius, rows - radius):
                minimum = np.min(data[y - radius: y + radius, x - radius: x + radius])
                maximum = np.max(data[y - radius: y + radius, x - radius: x + radius])
                out_data[y, x] = (data[y, x] * 1. - minimum * 1.) / (maximum * 1. - minimum * 1.) * np.iinfo(data.dtype).max
        out_ds.GetRasterBand(b + 1).WriteArray(out_data)
    out_ds = None
    ds = None
```

Ideally, I would also like to preserve the image size by inserting `np.pad(data, radius, mode='reflect')`, but then I'm not sure how to index everything correctly.

So how can I improve the performance of this?

---

In the meantime, I found a function from `skimage` [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/color_exposure/plot_local_equalize.html), which can do local stretching, but I need to do similar stuff with moving windows, so the principal question still remains.